# Hyperlinks not rendering Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I created a class that tries to parse hyperlinks from a set of labels and it seems to recognise the hyperlinks but doesn't ever change the correct span in a label to a hyperlink.
I first tried:

```
public class HtmlLabelConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var formatted = new FormattedString();

            foreach (var item in ProcessString((string)value))
                formatted.Spans.Add(CreateSpan(item));

            return formatted;
        }

        private Span CreateSpan(StringSection section)
        {
            var span = new Span()
            {
                Text = section.Text
            };

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(section.Link))
            {
                span.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer()
                {
                    Command = _navigationCommand,
                    CommandParameter = section.Link
                });
                span.TextColor = Color.Blue;
                span.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;
            }

            return span;
        }

        public IList<StringSection> ProcessString(string rawText)
        {
            const string spanPattern = @"(<a.*?>.*?</a>)";

            MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(rawText, spanPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);

            var sections = new List<StringSection>();

            var lastIndex = 0;

            foreach (Match item in collection)
            {
                var foundText = item.Value;
                sections.Add(new StringSection() { Text = rawText.Substring(lastIndex, item.Index) });
                lastIndex += item.Index + item.Length;

                // Get HTML href 
                var html = new StringSection()
                {
                    Link = Regex.Match(item.Value, "(?<=href=\\\")[\\S]+(?=\\\")").Value,
                    Text = Regex.Replace(item.Value, "<.*?>", string.Empty)
                };

                sections.Add(html);
            }

            sections.Add(new StringSection() { Text = rawText.Substring(lastIndex) });

            return sections;
        }

        public class StringSection
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
            public string Link { get; set; }
        }

        private ICommand _navigationCommand = new Command<string>((url) =>
        {
            //Device.OpenUri(new Uri(url));
            Launcher.TryOpenAsync(new Uri(url));
        });

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

with 
`<Label x:Name="labelParagraph"
               FormattedText="{Binding Paragraph, Converter={StaticResource HtmlLabelConverter}}"/>` in the xaml and the text in the format as follows `<a href="www.google.com"> link </a>` and it removes the `<a href>` parts from the text but does not turn the `link` to a hyperlink. This tells me it is finding the hyperlinks but for some reason does not execute the command.
Secondly I tried the following custom label:

```
public class LinksLabel : Label
    {
        public static BindableProperty LinksTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(LinksText), typeof(string), typeof(LinksLabel), propertyChanged: OnLinksTextPropertyChanged);

        private readonly ICommand _linkTapGesture = new Command<string>((url) => Device.OpenUri(new Uri(url)));

        public string LinksText
        {
            get => GetValue(LinksTextProperty) as string;
            set => SetValue(LinksTextProperty, value);
        }

        private void SetFormattedText()
        {
            var formattedString = new FormattedString();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LinksText))
            {
                var splitText = LinksText.Split(' ');

                foreach (string textPart in splitText)
                {
                    var span = new Span { Text = $"{textPart} " };

                    if (IsUrl(textPart)) // a link
                    {
                        span.TextColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
                        span.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
                        {
                            Command = _linkTapGesture,
                            CommandParameter = textPart
                        });
                    }

                    formattedString.Spans.Add(span);
                }
            }

            this.FormattedText = formattedString;
        }

        private bool IsUrl(string input)
        {
            return Uri.TryCreate(input, UriKind.Absolute, out var uriResult) &&
              (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);
        }

        private static void OnLinksTextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var linksLabel = bindable as LinksLabel;
            linksLabel.SetFormattedText();
        }
    }
```

With `<custom:LinksLabel
LinksText="blah blah blah www.google.com blah"/>`
But again this does not render anything to a hyperlink.

Comment: have you stepped through this in the debugger?

Comment: First solution works for me. You must be missing something.

Comment: The first solution was copied directly from my code so there must be something stopping it from working elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution it will give u the look and feel hyperlink.

XAML:

```
<Label HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="Hello " />
            <Span Text="Click Me!"
                  TextColor="Blue"
                  TextDecorations="Underline">
                <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="https://xamarin.com" />
                </Span.GestureRecognizers>
            </Span>
            <Span Text=" Some more text." />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

If you are using ViewModel create command or use tap gesture

```
public ICommand ClickCommand => new Command<string>((url) =>
{
    Device.OpenUri(new System.Uri(url));
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work because I need it to loop through paragraphs and find the hyperlinks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was creating and adding an extra scroll layout in the xaml.cs so that the page was scrollable, but it blocked anything from being clickable in the underlying stacklayout. I moved the `<ScrollView>` to the xaml file and it worked.